# Semantic-UI Dropdown doesn't show when using sidebar

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

When using a sidebar, if there is a dropdown in the pusher, the dropdown will not show outside of the pusher.

Why is this, and how can I resolve it? Just setting the `overflow-visible` doesn't seem to work.

Example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3djmjhn5/1/

Code:

```js
$('.sidebar').sidebar({
 context: '.pushable'
})

$('.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```css
.pushable {
  height: auto!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>

<h2>Dropdown doesn't Show when using sidebar</h2>

<div class="pushable">
  <div class="ui visible sidebar menu">
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="ui inverted menu">
      <div class="item">stuff</div>
      <div class="ui dropdown item">
            <div class="default text">select one</div>
            <input type="hidden" value="">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item">Stuff 1</div>                
                <div class="item">Stuff 2</div>
                <div class="item">Stuff 3</div>
                <div class="item">Stuff 4</div>
                <div class="item">Stuff 5</div>
                <div class="item">Stuff 6</div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Will Show Normally</h2>
<div class="ui inverted menu">
  <div class="item">stuff</div>
  <div class="ui dropdown item">
    <div class="default text">select one</div>
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">Stuff 1</div>                
      <div class="item">Stuff 2</div>
      <div class="item">Stuff 3</div>
      <div class="item">Stuff 4</div>
      <div class="item">Stuff 5</div>
      <div class="item">Stuff 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override the  overflow property of Semantic UI elements with `!important`. Have a look at the example below:

```js
$('.sidebar').sidebar({
 context: '.pushable'
})

$('.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```css
.pushable {
  height: auto!important;
}

.pusher {
overflow: visible!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>

<h2>Dropdown doesn't Show when using sidebar</h2>

<div class="pushable">
  <div class="ui visible sidebar menu">
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="ui inverted menu">
      <div class="item">stuff</div>
      <div class="ui dropdown item">
            <div class="default text">select one</div>
            <input type="hidden" value="">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item">Stuff 1</div>                
                <div class="item">Stuff 2</div>
                <div class="item">Stuff 3</div>
                <div class="item">Stuff 4</div>
                <div class="item">Stuff 5</div>
                <div class="item">Stuff 6</div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Will Show Normally</h2>
<div class="ui inverted menu">
  <div class="item">stuff</div>
  <div class="ui dropdown item">
    <div class="default text">select one</div>
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">Stuff 1</div>                
      <div class="item">Stuff 2</div>
      <div class="item">Stuff 3</div>
      <div class="item">Stuff 4</div>
      <div class="item">Stuff 5</div>
      <div class="item">Stuff 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm accept the initial answer and ask a new question, as my example doesn't reflect my actual problem (as I've come to find out). The problem I am having was with two of the sidebars below each other. It seem the `transform3d` messes up the z-index on elements, not that there are hidden overflows.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of overflow: hidden on classes .pusher and .pushable.

Setting overflow: visible on then will fix it.

Add id to your .pusher (i.e. my-pusher) and update css to:

```
.pushable {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
#my-pusher.pusher {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

[Check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3djmjhn5/3/)

Comment: Hm, my example must not be representative enough of my use case, I have the overflow set to visible. I need to modify the example. Will comment back when that is complete

Comment: first I've also was caught until added id, some rule in the internals of that "semantic-ui" lib had higher priority. in any case just check consecutively parents, it should be overflow.